# CVXPY DCPError: Problem does not follow DCP rules for minimization

Tags: python, cvxpy

I'm trying to solve a problem that finds the minimum of V value that would minimize the trace of Quad Form `V'@W@V` where V is 3x1, and W which is 3x3 matrix. With constrains `` V`@Q@V <= I ``, where Q is a 3x3 matrix.  I'm new to cvxpy, but as far as I understand the constraints here are given correctly.

Edit: As Micheal pointed out if `V` is `3x1` and `W 3x3` `V'WV` will be a scalar. I redefined, V to be a 6x2 matrix, W as a 6x6 matrix. Which should result in a 2x2 matrix of which I want to minimize the diagonal entries.

```
V = cp.Variable(shape=(6,2))

objective = cp.Minimize(cp.trace(cp.quad_form(V,W)))

con = cp.quad_form(V,Q)

cons = [con<=np.eye(3)]

prob = cp.Problem(objective, cons)

result = prob.solve()
```

Raises an error

```
DCPError: Problem does not follow DCP rules. Specifically:
The objective is not DCP. Its following subexpressions are not:
var461 @ [[-1.          0.         -1.          0.         -0.77910125 -0.23003633]
 [ 0.         -1.          0.         -1.          0.51523716  0.31351064]
 [-1.          0.          0.          0.         -0.43932559  0.06076264]
 [ 0.         -1.          0.          0.          0.43042035  0.59073962]
 [-0.33977566  0.0848168  -0.43932559  0.43042035 -0.74982669 -0.26546118]
 [-0.29079897 -0.27722898  0.06076264  0.59073962 -0.26546118  0.01021432]] @ var461
```

Looking for correction on how to define V, correctly.

Comment: The matrix appearing in the error message has a -1 in the upper left corner so it is clearly not PSD. So you are trying to define a nonconvex objective. Also quad_form returns a scalar so there is no point taking trace or comparing it to a matrix.

Comment: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disciplined-convex-programming

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek You're absolutely correct, but you can solve non-convex problems with cvxpy refer to this link <https://www.cvxpy.org/examples/basic/quadratic_program.html> . Also correct about trace, I have corrected that error, but it still doesn't admit a solution.

Comment: I'd be more than surprised if CVXPY could be used for nonconvex QP. The quadratic matrix still needs to be PSD. Also you would need a nonconvex QP solver so probably only Gurobi or CPLEX from the ones available via CVXPY. Maybe it is possible in Pyomo.